# How to send result from activity to fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I Have Activity A, Inside that activity there is one fragment called F1 and  inside that fragment i have another fragment F2. From F2 I called startActivityForResult(/*Activity B*/) and then when finishing activity B. onActivityResult() of fragment F2 is getting called but i want same thing to be happened in F1.
What I want is Fragment F1 should get the event that Activity B is finished.
Any help on this is appreciated.

Comment: in the callback method you can invoke another method of Fragment F1

Comment: It is not recommended to create the object and call the methods of another fragment directly.

Comment: yes i know, you can use an interface for that

Comment: Can you please provide a [mcve] of the code?

Comment: Do you want both F1 and F2 to get the event? Or just F1?

Comment: Only for Fragment F1.

Answer (score 0):

Hi You need to get the current fragment form Fragment manager in Activity's

```
onActivityResult()  Method.
```

Just make a call to fragment's onActivityResult() method.

```
CustomFragment fragment = (CustomFragment ) getFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(getFragmentManager().getLastBackStackEntry());
fragment.onActivityResult();
```

You can use this technique.

Answer (score 0):

You are most likely calling `StartActivityForResult` from your `F2` fragment. Since you don't want the result going back to `F2`, you need to call that method on fragment `F1` instead.

It would be nice to see some code to see what you are actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

**From your question it seems that F2 is child fragment for F1.**

If so you can call startActivityForResult method from fragment F2 as below :

```
    getParentFragment().startActivityForResult(intent, requestCode);
```

Now, when you will finish the second activity, it will automatically call onActivityResult() method of parent fragment (i.e. Fragment F1).